# How to get subviews frames early in initialization process

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am changing some code from XIBs to storyboard.  There seems to be a substantial difference in the timing of setting frame bounds of the subviews of a storyboard scene.

A technique this code frequently uses is this:

- a UIView subview has dimensions defined in the XIB or storyboard file (allowing somebody other than the programmer to modify the UI)
- The UIViewController has a link to the object as an `IBObject UIView *`
- in the UIViewController's `- viewWillAppear()`, certain calculations are made and drawing is done based upon those calculations.

For example, in our XIB or Storyboard file, there's a UIView that we wish to cut up into four regions.  The controller looks at the bounds of that UIView, looks at its frame, and then in the UIView draws four boxes, each one quarter the size.

In .h:

```
IBOutlet UIView *outputColorKeyView;
```

In .m's `viewWillAppear`:

```
CGRect keyBounds = [outputColorKeyView bounds];

float high = keyBounds.size.height;
float wide = keyBounds.size.width;

float cellWidth = wide/4.0;

XLog(@"Dimensions for the color key are: %f %f", high, wide);
```

My problem is that under XIBs, this worked fine: I was able to see that the dimensions of the region I had to draw in was 200 points wide (for example), and the cells could be drawn 50 points wide.

Under Storyboards, this is no longer working for me: I get a frame of (0,0,0,0) when I am calling from the controller's `viewWillAppear` method:

`[18:09:16.901|4096] Dimensions for the color key are: 0.000000 0.000000`

However, run from later in the program's life cycle (triggered by a button), I get the correct result:

`[18:09:35.812|4096] Dimensions for the color key are: 36.000000 734.000000`

Is there any way to get this information before the view appears?  I would think so, but `viewWillAppear` seems like the last opportunity before views are actually rendered.  Or is there some obvious switch that I am missing that will make this technique work as intended?

Thanks

Comment: Something else is going on there.  If the `IBOutlet` is hooked up correctly and the view is a proper subview of the view controller's `view` property then it should be available as early as `viewDidLoad:`...which is before `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: OK, thanks - that's good to know. The code is dropped in right from the XIB version, so it seems like it should be working identically - but the fact that the dimensions are not available from viewWillAppear but not available later (with no manipulation of the view by other other method) had me wondering.

Comment: My main thought was whether there might be a setting to the UIView in the Storyboard that non-obviously has this subtle side effect.  I'll try to duplicate the issue in some fresh code.

Comment: OK, I am getting the same behavior from a completely fresh project, empty storyboard (this is the second scene, connected by a single button with a mode transition).

Comment: Empty storyboard except for two scenes (this is the second scene, connected by a single button with a mode transition).  The second scene is a single UIView.  When I do this in the scene controller's viewDidLoad: 

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"---------------------------");
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad[TestGameController]: my view is: %@", [self view]);
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad[TestGameController]: my subview1 is: %@", subViewOne);
}`

Comment: I get:

2012-11-15 14:38:03.801 testStoryBoardSubViews[10666:c07] viewDidLoad[TestGameController]: my view is: <UIView: 0x10019910; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10019970>>
2012-11-15 14:38:03.801 testStoryBoardSubViews[10666:c07] viewDidLoad[TestGameController]: my subview1 is: <UIView: 0x10019760; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x100197c0>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was given in an answer to my [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406574/gettting-subviews-frames-in-storyboard) ... the place to do this stuff is after the layout is done, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

It is not clear to me why the information changed, from the data in the initial description file (whether XIB or Storyboard) being available as early as `viewDidLoad` to now being (0,0,0,0), but it *is* a difference to be aware of if you follow a lot of the tutorial code out there in books and on the net.

Comment: I think I've discovered that the key item in the equation is whether or not "Autolayout" is enabled for the xib/storyboard.  Without "Autolayout" the frames established in IB are used to set up the view sizes in the hierarchy during loading.  When "Autolayout" is enabled, the sizing is deferred until subview layout (as you mention above).