# Getting subViews' frames in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I just want (for now) to get the dimensions of a subview on the view controller's instantiation.

[This is a reduction to as simple a case I can find of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389750/how-to-get-subviews-frames-early-in-initialization-process).  I am trying to figure out why subViews of scenes in Storyboards are not behaving the way I expect, which is to say: like XIBs do - I just want to get dimensions of my subviews before anything is actually drawn to the screen]

To condense the problem down to a new, clean project, I do this:

- create a new, single view project with "using Storyboard" checked
- add a single UIView to the default existing `MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard` (and change its background to green to make it more easily seen - beyond shrinking the dimensions some, this is the only change I make from the default UIView I drag onto the scene)
- option-click the `ViewController.h` file in the navigator to bring it up in its own frame underneath the Storyboard frame and insert a pair of braces underneath the `@interface` directive
- control-click-and-drag from the UIView in the Storyboard to `ViewController.h` and tell it to name the outlet `firstViewFirstSubView`

So we now have for `ViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *firstViewFirstSubView;
}
@end
```

Then, I add this method to the ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"View Controller will appear. firstViewFirstSubView: %@ ", firstViewFirstSubView);
    NSLog(@"subView's dimmensions: %f by %f at %f, %f", firstViewFirstSubView.frame.size.width,
      firstViewFirstSubView.frame.size.height,
      firstViewFirstSubView.frame.origin.x,
      firstViewFirstSubView.frame.origin.y);
}
```

At this point, I expect to be able to get the dimensions of the UIView subview.  I get all 0s, though:

```
2012-11-15 15:21:00.743 StoryboardViewBounds[11132:c07] View Controller will appear. firstViewFirstSubView: <UIView: 0x9379730; frame = (0 0; 0 0); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9378e40>> 
2012-11-15 15:21:00.744 StoryboardViewBounds[11132:c07] subView's dimmensions: 0.000000 by 0.000000 at 0.000000, 0.000000
```

What am I doing wrong?  It seems like this should be very straightforward, so I think I must be missing something simple, whether throwing the right switch in the Storyboard editor or implementing a method that Storyboard needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those dimensions are calculated and set when the call to `layoutSubviews` is made, which occurs after `viewWillAppear`. After `layoutSubviews` is called on the UIVIew you can get the dimensions.

Look at implementing this method in your view controller: `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. At this point you should be able to get dimensions of your subviews. Note that this call is available starting in iOS 5.0 but since you reference storyboards I assume you are working at or above that anyway.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"View Controller did layout subviews. firstViewFirstSubView: %@ ", firstViewFirstSubView);
    NSLog(@"subView's dimmensions: %f by %f at %f, %f", firstViewFirstSubView.frame.size.width,
      firstViewFirstSubView.frame.size.height,
      firstViewFirstSubView.frame.origin.x,
      firstViewFirstSubView.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Comment: This did it, thank you! I wonder why the availability of the initial information from the layout file changed between when we used XIB files (and the tutorial code I worked with all worked with XIB files, going as early as `viewDidLoad`) and when they implemented Storyboard.

In any case - thank you!

Answer (score 8):

There is a Related issue that I am compelled to address, which hopefully will save someone else a day of debugging:

I am finding out that in Storyboard:

1. **`segue-push`** does **not** cause `subView`s to be laid out at `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` (*they are instead laid out at some other time just before `-viewDidAppear`*).
   **Whereas**...
2. **`segue-modal`** and `[navController.storyboard presentViewController:]` **does** cause `subViews` to be laid out at `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

The solution is to put `[self.mySubView layoutSubviews]` within the `viewController`'s `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` method in order to manually load the `subView`s within `mySubView`.

My case was that I had a custom gradient button that was not properly initializing it's visual appearance.
The button was contained within a `scrollView` that contained a `CustomView` which contained the custom gradient button.
So, basically... a button within a view within a `scrollView`.

The app starts out with a `UINavigationController` having some other `ViewController1` loaded.
`ViewController1` contains a button which, when pressed, launches a storyboard **`segue-push`** to `ViewController2`.
(*this was arranged in storyboard by control-dragging from the button in `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`*).

`ViewController2` contains the `scrollview`/`customView`/`customButton`.
In `ViewController2`'s `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`, I initialize the `customButton` which is a custom Gradient Button having it's own **.h/.m** files.
`GradientButton.m` has an `initLayers` method which configures it graphically and requires the `bounds`/`frame` property of the button to be initialized.
**However**...
in `ViewController2`'s `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`, `self.customButton` had a frame of 0,0,0,0.

### A few notes:

1. Yes, I am calling `[super viewDidLayoutSubviews]` at the beginning of `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`.
2. The only view that has been laid out at `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` is `self.view` (`ViewController2`'s initial view, as connected in Storyboard's connections panel. *in my case - `self.view` is a `scrollView`*).

### To resolve:

1. in `ViewController2`, I created an outlet `self.bottomView` for the view that contained `self.customButton`.
2. in `ViewController2`'s `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`, I call `[self.bottomView layoutSubviews]`

   - This will then cause `customButton`'s frame/bounds to be properly set.
3. Next, I call `[self.customButton initLayers]` which now properly initializes my custom gradient button.

A few notes about `ViewController2`'s `-viewDidLayoutSubviews:` calling `[self.view layoutSubviews]` causes `bottomView`'s frame to be initialized, but NOT `customButton`'s frame.
In terms of a view hierarchy, `-layoutSubviews` applies only to the `subView`s of `self.view` and not to any `subView`s of those `subView`s.
This only appears to be the case with storyboard **`segue-push`**.

The  storyboard **`segue-modal`** and the programmatic `[navController presentViewController]` both seem to  correctly initialize all levels of the view hierarchy (all "`subView`s of `subView`s") by the time `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called.

Comment: much appreciated, encountering the exact same situation