# UITextView's frame not set in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm using iOS 6 and Xcode 4.6 and with the Interface Builder I'm adding a `UITextView` in a `scrollbar view`.

I disabled the scrolling for the `Text View` and I would like to dynamically resize the `Text View` so that we can view the full content.

I tried with the following code in my controller :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect frame = _description.frame;
    frame.size.height = _description.contentSize.height;
    _description.frame = frame;
}
```

`_description` is bound to the `UITextView`.

In this code the frame is at position `(0, 0)` and has a size of `(0, 0)`. As a consequence it does not resize my `UITextView`.

I also tried to resize the view in these functions with no success :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad;
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;
```

The only function where it works (the frame as a size greater than 0) is :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

However, at this point the view is already visible and we can see the `Text View` resizing (which is not what I want. I want it to resize before the user can see the view).

Can you tell me why my `UITextView's` frame is not correct and how I can solve this issue ?

For your information, this view is displayed automatically with the push method by a `TableViewCell` (configured in the storyboard).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer thanks to Cezar's comment.

The answer can be found here [Gettting subViews' frames in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406574/gettting-subviews-frames-in-storyboard) .

I actually called :

```
[_view layoutSubviews];
```

on my parent's view in the :

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews;
```

method before accessing the frame and it works.