# Content of scrollview changes size when scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode4, interface-builder

I'm using iOS 6 and Xcode 4.6 and with the Interface Builder I added to my controller a `UIScrollView` that uses all the available space. In this `UIScrollView` I added some views (a `UIImageView`, a `UITextView` and a `UITableView` (I disabled the scrolling for the `UITextView` and the `UITableView`)).

In the :

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews;
```

method I resized all my views by increasing their height (to fit with their respective content).
Then, I set the contentSize of my `UIScrollView` so that it fits with its content (my 3 views).

The resizing works and I can see them in my application when I run it.
Also, the scrolling is good (the contentSize is correct as I can scroll).

However, I have one big issue : as soon as I scroll, my 3 views are resized to their initial size (instead of keeping the size I assigned them via the frame property).

All my views are added with Interface Builder to my storyboard.

Do you know what I did wrong? Why my `UIScrollView's` content is reseting its size when I scroll?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why don't u use viewDidLoad method? I used viewDidLoad method, when had same tasks and it worked well for me.

Comment: yes as Timur said, you need to right your code in viewDidLoad method. because when UIScrollView scrolls, it calls the layoutSubviews method of it and its subviews too. It will lead their subviews to go to their original position.

Comment: I already tried to resize my views in viewDidLoad but it does not work (I opened a question for this issue by the way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907178/uitextviews-frame-not-set-in-viewwillappear/17908561) (it's because my controller is loaded from a push event and views are added from storyboard). So I have to change the size in viewDidLayoutSubviews. How should I proceed ?

Comment: You can try adding setAutoResizeSubView to NO for you scrollView

Comment: My proposal is to add subview in viewDidLoad, not in IB, because subview anyway changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have auto layout enabled in your storyboard.  When you scroll the scroll view, auto layout runs and resets your subview frames based on the constraints in the storyboard.

There are a few ways to fix this.  One way is to turn off auto layout in your storyboard.  Another way is to connect outlets to the constraints in your storyboard, and update the constraints (instead of setting the frames) to make auto layout put the views where you want them.